# Determine classes used by a Java application

Tags: java, deployment, class, java-web-start

How would you determine the classes (non Sun JDK classes) loaded /  unused by a Java application?

**Background:**
I have an `legacy` Java webstart application that has gone through a lot of code changes and now has a lot of classes, most of which are not used. I would like to reduce the download size of the application by only deploying classes that will be used only instead of jaring the all the packages.

I will also use the same process to completely delete these unused classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `java -verbose:class` to see what classes are loaded, then use grep (or any other tool) to keep only the lines from your packages.

A small limitation: it will only tell you which classes are really used **when** they are used, so you must cover all use cases of your application.

Comment: Although this is a good option you have to make sure you "touch" every single part of your application to have that class loaded. Otherwise you may end up not considering classes but just because you didn't  play with them.

Comment: The OP mentions webstart is being used.  I'm also using webstart.  How can the `-verbose:class` option be used with webstart?  I have it in my JNLP file as follows, but this doesn't work: `<j2se version="1.8+" max-heap-size="1024M" java-vm-args="-verbose:class"/>`  Note the other options in this line do work (like the heap-size).  So I know the line is being processed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a good IDE for that.

For instance [Intellij IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) which analyzes the source code for dependencies and allows you to [safely delete](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/refactoring.html#Safe_Delete) a class/method/attribute is is not being used by any other.

That way you can get rid off all your dead code.

Comment: Same goes for NetBeans with the safe delete concept, you can right-click and choose "Find Usages" on anything from variables to classes to find out exactly where it is used (or if it is not used at all).

Comment: @n002213f : There must be. I bet it is very well hidden in one of those multiple "perspectives" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238177/worst-ui-youve-ever-used/568142#568142

Comment: @Kavon Farvardin - and i do that for all the classes in the project, there must be a better way

Comment: Right click on the identifier; it's in the contextual menu

Comment: @ Steven Schlansker - please elaborate